# how to require --ask-become-pass in ansible without a command-line flag

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that requires an sudo pass.  I call the playbook with the --ask-become-pass and it works.  It is possible to specify in the playbook so that it always asks for the sudo/become pass without the command line flag?

Answer (score 11):

You cannot do this in a playbook, because password options are processed by the CLI before it opens a playbook file.
However, you may enable the [become_ask_pass](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-become-ask-pass) configuration option to force ansible binaries to always ask for the become password.  To enable this option, enter it in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` or `~/.ansible.cfg` in the `[privilege_escalation]` section:

```
[privilege_escalation]
become_ask_pass=True
```

Note that this causes Ansible to *always* ask for the escalation password, even for a simple command like `ansible --list-hosts`.

Comment: Thanks! That seems very strange since the become settings and become user are processed in the playbook.

Comment: You can check [the code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py#L103). I think it is because, you are encouraged to use key auth instead of passwords.

Comment: I think their security model makes it better to process passwords in the CLI before it gets to the playbook processing, but regardless the best practice is definitely to switch from passwords to keys. This is really trivial to do and increases your security by a huge margin.

Comment: `become_ask_pass` has to be in the `[privilege_escalation]` of `ansible.cfg`